# Excel gives me syntax error in the script that looks just as in the tutorial

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a script for Excel and it keeps showing me an error "syntax error" at the line "Return ..." But I don't see any problem with the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
Function LoadCurrentUnitArray() As String()

    Dim currentUnitArray() As String, unit_count As Integer, i As Integer

   

    unit_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(2))

    ReDim currentUnitArray(unit_count)

    For i = 1 To unit_count

        currentUnitArray(i) = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value

    Next

    Return currentUnitArray

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: There's no `Return` in VBA: `LoadCurrentUnitArray = currentUnitArray`.

Comment: Side note: use `Long`, not `Integer`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) why.

Comment: Thank you! I opened Excel Developer tab for the first time today, didn't know Visual Basic and VBA are different things. And thanks for the data type tip.

Comment: You can take a screenshot in Windows by pressing `WIN+SHIFT+S` then you can select the area you want to snip. The snip tool puts the image in your clipboard where you can post directly to SO by pressing `CTRL+V`. Much faster than taking a picture with an external device. You will get better image quality too.

Comment: @HackSlash Thank you for advice. Unfortunetelly I was making the post from phone and coded on different device, where I cannot access stackexchange. I just wanted to show the kind of environment I am coding in in case there was something specific to it. Sorry for the ruined aesthetics.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for the editor tip. Will try it next time.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon why is the multiple-declarations Dim statement a problem?